# Scala.js exporting abstract val/var

Tags: scala, scala.js

It seems that exporting abstract val/var with descendants like this doesn't work:

```
@JSExportDescendentObjects
trait T {
  @JSExport
  val i: Int
  @JSExport
  var j: Int
}

class A extends T {
  val i = 5
  var j = 10
}
```

I get warnings `no valid targets for annotation on value i - it is discarded unused` and `A`'s `i` and `j` are not seen from Javascript. However, it is possible to export them via `@JSExportAll`:

```
@JSExportDescendentObjects
@JSExportAll
trait T {
  val i: Int
  var j: Int
}

class A extends T {
  val i = 5
  var j = 10
}
```

It is fine now, no warnings and `i` and `j` are visible from JS.

`def`s doesn't have such problem. Why is this and how can I selectively export abstract val/var?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This was [a bug](https://github.com/scala-js/scala-js/issues/2513) in Scala.js <= 0.6.10. Upgrading to Scala.js 0.6.11 should fix your problem.